# Previous 5 Years Data based on a Specific Year

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, date

I have a table like this:

```
ID|Date    |Name|Score  
1 |1/1/2014|Erin|20.2  
2 |6/3/2014|Erin|21.2  
3 |7/2/2015|Emil|34.2    
4 |1/1/2016|Erin|20.2  
5 |2/2/2011|Paul|20.2  
6 |1/1/2012|John|54.2  
7 |1/1/2017|John|54.2  
8 |12/31/2016|Erin|23.2
```

I want the data back 5 years based on the year I provide.
I am using this:

```
select * from tblStdnt where date > DATEADD(Year,DATEDIFF(year,0, '2016')- 5, 0)
```

But this gives me data starting from 2017. How do I fix this? any ideas?

It should give me:

> all data from 2011 to 2016 (the 5 year period, regardless of the month or day)

**UPDATE**
[DBFiddle link](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=a842bd0eecc96039e61412d5bfdeefb3)

Comment: your query as written should return the entire sample table. Are you saying the query does not return all results with a date greater than 2011-01-01?

Comment: It is, but it is giving me 2017 as well. I just want 5 years before the year I provide i.e. 2016

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: 2011 to 2016 is a 6 year period, by the way ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the "magic" values of `1900` (the year of the "zero" date) and `0` (or "date zero" which is `'1900-01-01'`) we can produce the 1st January of the two years we need (5 years ago and 1 year ahead):

```
SELECT *
FROM tblStdnt
WHERE DATEADD(year, 2016 - 1900 - 5, 0) 
      <= date
  AND    date < DATEADD(year, 2016 - 1900 + 1, 0) ;
```

In recent versions (2012+), it's easier with the [`DATEFROMPARTS(year, month, day)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql) function:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblStdnt
WHERE DATEFROMPARTS(2016 - 5, 1, 1)
      <= date
  AND    date < DATEFROMPARTS(2016 + 1, 1, 1) ;
```

---

*Note:* the query - because the condition is against the column (`date`) and not on an expression - *may*<sup>*</sup> use an index on that column. Queries that have conditions with expressions on the columns (like `YEAR(date) >= ..`) are unlikely to use an index, unless there is an index on a computed column with the specific expression or a similar indexed view.

<sup>*</sup> "may": Since we want data that spans 6 years - so probably a large portion of the table - a table scan may still be used. Using similar conditions ("SARGable") is considered good practice though. Consider the case where the clustered index of the table is or starts with the `date` column. Immediately the plan can be a partial scan instead of a table scan. The `YEAR(date)` queries will still have to do a full table scan.

Comment: All the answers here work with what I need but my actual table is HUGE and yper makes a good point of SARGable queries. I found mathewb answer to be the next best in simplicity and brevity.

Answer (score 4):

You only need to use [**DATEADD**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql)

> ```
> DECLARE @DT date = '20150101';
>
> SELECT DATEADD(year, -5, @DT);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name)    |
> | :------------------ |
> | 01/01/2010 00:00:00 |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=7f7690e3a47c41d4dc47dd3e4734292d)*

**UPDATE**

As far as you need all data between two years you can use the next sentence:

```
DECLARE @DT date = '20160101';

SELECT * 
FROM   tblStdnt 
WHERE  YEAR(date) >= YEAR(@DT) - 5
AND    YEAR(date) <= YEAR(@DT);
```

According to your sample data:

> ```
> ID | Date                | Name | Score
> -: | :------------------ | :--- | :----
>  1 | 01/01/2014 00:00:00 | Erin | 20.20
>  2 | 31/03/2014 00:00:00 | Erin | 21.20
>  3 | 07/02/2015 00:00:00 | Emil | 22.20
>  4 | 31/12/2016 00:00:00 | Erin | 23.20
>  5 | 02/02/2011 00:00:00 | Paul | 24.20
>  6 | 31/12/2011 00:00:00 | John | 25.20
>  7 | 01/01/2012 00:00:00 | John | 26.20
>  9 | 01/01/2013 00:00:00 | Emil | 26.20
> 11 | 01/01/2016 00:00:00 | Erin | 29.20
> ```

> ```
> DECLARE @DT date = '20160101';
>
> SELECT YEAR(@DT) - 5 AS StartDate,
>        YEAR(@DT) AS EndDate;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> StartDate | EndDate
> --------: | ------:
>      2011 |    2016
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=421fe632297bb5c130c20a484d6cd8ac)*

Comment: This is a better way to write this but it give the same result as OP, so probably not the issue

Comment: @McNets This gives me the same result as I am getting

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the problem you're running into is that you are only specifying a minimum date. The way your query is written, you will get everything from five years prior to the date through the end of time. You need to specify both a start and end point for your range to eliminate the data occurring after the date specified. One way to write this would be:

```
DECLARE @dateToEnd SMALLINT
SET @dateToEnd = 2016
SELECT  *
FROM    tblStdnt S
WHERE   YEAR(S.date) BETWEEN (@dateToEnd - 5) AND @dateToEnd
```

Note that this answer actually gives six full years of data - the year selected and the five preceding years.

Comment: I want it to be based on years. If I change one of the dates in the table to 12/31/2016 then it does not get included...I have updated the question and added a new row to show what I mean

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblStdnt 
WHERE YEAR(Date) <= 2016 and YEAR(DATE) > 2016-5
```

If it's only a small dataset that should work well enough. For larger datasets you may hit issues with the statement not being SARGable.